Template CustomButton doesn't exist
I am the one who invited to learn about odoo 15, I am trying to learn about custom PoS but there are some errors I don't know where I am wrong, I hope everyone can help
odoo.define('a_custom_pos_not.CustomButton', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    console.log('Have JS file');
    const PosComponent = require('point_of_sale.PosComponent');
    const ProductScreen = require('point_of_sale.ProductScreen');
    const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');

        class CustomButton extends Posx`zW` {

    }

    CustomButton.template = "CustomButton";

    ProductScreen.addControlButton({
        component: CustomButton,
        condition: function () {
            return true;
        },
        position: ['before', 'OrderlineCustomerNoteButton']
    });


    Registries.Component.add(CustomButton);
    return CustomButton;
});

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-name="CustomButton" owl="1">
            <div class="control-button">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" role="img" aria-label="Custom" title="Custom Button"/>
                Custom
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
</odoo>

{
    'name': 'Custom POS Notification',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'Point of Sale',
    'summary': 'Add a custom button next to Info button in POS',
    'description': 'This module adds a custom button to the POS interface.',
    'depends': ['point_of_sale'],
    'data': [],
    'assets': {
        'point_of_sale.assets': [
            'a_custom_pos_not/static/src/xml/custom_button.xml',
            'a_custom_pos_not/static/src/js/custom_button.js'
        ],
    },
    'installable': True,
    'application': False,
}

I have checkes manifest file and i make sure it correct

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
